# Angularjs Jasmine Test: Making api call with $backend

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have run into an issue, that after at least 8 hours of searching and tinkering and coming up empty handed requires some help from the community. There are articles that attempt to address similar issues but the examples are lacking and provide a little help, but not totally. After reading I come up with the following modules and tests that I have not been able to figure out the $backend for the ngWeather factory. Whenever I try to .flush() the $backend I get the error of no pending request. While this is an issue I'm also not sure the url that is passed to the JSONP request is mocked out correctly. Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**[Here is a link to the plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Xz9OWB/preview)**

/* Module and Controller JS */

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngWeather) {
    ngWeather.getWeather(139,35).then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data.data;
    });
});


app.factory('ngWeather', function ($http) {
   return {
       getWeather : function (lat, lon, callback) {
           $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
             .then(function(data) {
                 callback({
                     data : data.data,
                     city : data.data.name,
                     temp : Math.floor(data.data.main.temp*(9/5)-459.67),
                     minTemp : Math.floor(data.data.main.temp_min*(9/5)-459.67),
                     maxTemp : Math.floor(data.data.main.temp_max*(9/5)-459.67),
                     humidity : data.data.main.humidity,
                     currentCondition : data.data.weather[0].main,
                     currentDescription : data.data.weather[0].description,
                     icon : data.data.weather[0].icon
                 });
             });
       }
   };
});
```

/* Tests */

```
describe('Test: ngWeather', function() {

  var ngWeather = jasmine.createSpyObj('ngWeather', ['getWeather']);
  var $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(module('test'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.when('jsonp', '*/api.openweathermap.org/*')
      .respond({
        data : {"coord":{"lon":0,"lat":0},"sys":{"message":0.0472,"country":"US","sunrise":1383998825,"sunset":1384035744},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"gdps stations","main":{"temp":289.68,"humidity":35,"pressure":958,"temp_min":276.48,"temp_max":301.48},"wind":{"speed":4.11,"gust":5.65,"deg":169},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1384022616,"id":4291884,"name":"Flatwoods","cod":200},
        city : 'Flatwoods',
        temp : 63,
        minTemp : 55,
        maxTemp : 68,
        humidity : 70,
        currentCondition : 'Clouds',
        currentDescription : 'Overcast clouds',
        icon : '04n'
      });
  }));

  it('should check if getWeather method is defined', function() {
    expect(ngWeather.getWeather).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should check if a value is returned', function() {
    ngWeather.getWeather(139,35,function(data) {
      expect(data).not.toBe(null);
    });
  });

  it('should check if a Flatwoods is returned as city', function() {
    ngWeather.getWeather(139,35, function(data) {
      expect(data.city).toEqual('Flatwoods');
    });
  });

  it('should make a call to the api', function() {
    $httpBackend.expect('jsonp', '*/api.openweathermap.org/*')
      .respond({
        data : {"coord":{"lon":0,"lat":0},"sys":{"message":0.0472,"country":"US","sunrise":1383998825,"sunset":1384035744},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"gdps stations","main":{"temp":289.68,"humidity":35,"pressure":958,"temp_min":276.48,"temp_max":301.48},"wind":{"speed":4.11,"gust":5.65,"deg":169},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1384022616,"id":4291884,"name":"Flatwoods","cod":200},
        city : 'Flatwoods',
        temp : 63,
        minTemp : 55,
        maxTemp : 68,
        humidity : 70,
        currentCondition : 'Clouds',
        currentDescription : 'Overcast clouds',
        icon : '04n'
      });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    ngWeather.getWeather(139,35, function(data) {
      expect(data.temp).toEqual('63');
    });


  });
});
```

This is my first go at writing tests but I would like to promote quality code and I feel it is essential I learn. Again any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, **[Here is a link to the plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Xz9OWB/preview)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plnkr that you shared was not actually invoking the `getWeather` function during the tests and hence your test cases were not executing the `expect` in the callbacks at all. Therefore, you were getting "*No pending request to flush*". You should be able to verify that by adding any logging statements.
I have forked and modified your plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/REaMj6E9VmWXieVeSmm7) to be able to run the tests with your mock data. The data that you had mocked had different structure than your code was expecting. You should now be able to see it working [here](http://plnkr.co/REaMj6E9VmWXieVeSmm7).

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks a lot. Where this is my first test I really needed a familiar visual to understand how to mock and implement one. You supplied that. Your help is greatly appreciated.